# Why are we able to use the uncertainty principle in quantum mechanics to calculate momentum/position?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was asked the following question in my textbook:

> The nitrogen molecule consists of two nitrogen atoms joined by a covalent bond with length approximately 100pm. What is the approximate kinetic energy of the covalently bonded electrons?

The process to solving this is to use the uncertainty relation

$$\Delta p \Delta x \approx \hbar$$

and insert 100pm into $\Delta x$ to solve for $\Delta p$. Then you use

$$E = \frac{p^2}{2m_e}$$

where $m_e$ is the mass of an electron to find the kinetic energy.

I understand that $\Delta x$ is around 100pm because that's the distance between the nitrogen atoms, so it's generally the range in which the electron can roam. But then we use that $\Delta x$ to find $\Delta p$ and treat $\Delta p$ as though it were just momentum $p$. Why can we say, in this instance, that $\Delta p = p$?

Comment: If $\langle p\rangle =0$ then $\Delta p$ can be, roughly considered as $p$

Comment: That makes sense. Can we assume here that ⟨⟩=0?

Comment: I would assume so as the electrons are bound to the nuclei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, under the Born approximation, nuclei at rest compared to the electron motion. Thus effectively the electrons are bound within a region by the nuclei. This means that the average momentum of the electrons must be zero.

Thus in this case, the spread in momentum is itself roughly, the momentum. $\Delta p\approx p$